# Why does Android Marshallow UITest Reboots Device

Tags: android, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-reboot, uitest

When trying to update our app to work correctly with Android Marshmallow (API lvl 23) I went to run our UITest tests and found that on both physical devices and on the emulator the entire device reboots as if it has crashed.

This occurs when both running each test individually (first one passes, then reboots on second) and on running all tests.

I have testing this on a Nexus 5, 6, and 9 emulator and a physical 5 and 6 with fresh Marshmallow upgrade with the same behavior.

Has anyone else come across this problem or know of a solution?

Comment: can you provide some logging up until the reboot?

Comment: I updated to the latest SDK and UITest 1.2 and the problem appears to have gone away.  I can't find any reference to this problem in the changelogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Emulator (Intel system image) revision 8 for `Android M 6.0 (API 23)` and `UITest 1.2` this no longer occurs.
I'm not sure what was causing the problem, but updating fixed.